# vswprintf MinGW, странная декларация

Tags: c, mingw

Функция `vswprintf` в MinGW, откуда он её берёт?

Декларацию функции так раскопать и не удалось, путём подбора и шаманских плясок с бубном, получилась рабочая версия декларации:

```
     int vswprintf(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, va_list);
```

в студии стандартный вариант:

```
     int vswprintf(wchar_t*, size_t, const wchar_t*, va_list);
```

*nix версия функции аналогична из MSVC

где  MinGW её берёт то? и где она реально объявлена ?

при всем при этом `vswprintf` из MinGW ещё и размер не возвращает..

вот скриншот подобранной декларации и поведения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот скриншот стандартной декларации и поведения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

версия MinGW: `mingw32/gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm-1)`

Comment: Не понял. Стандартный вариант `vswprintf` возвращает `int` (а не `size_t`) и объявлен в `<wchar.h>`.

Comment: Пусть будет так, не о том вопрос, сейчас поправлю, не в unsigned дело

Comment: В таких вопросах нужно сразу писать, как вы определили, что в MinGW именно такой прототип у этой функции. У меня в MinGW-w64 все нормально: `int vswprintf (wchar_t *__stream, size_t __count, const wchar_t *__format, __builtin_va_list __local_argv)` (файл `./i686-w64-mingw32/include/swprintf.inl`).

Comment: Путём мата компилятора и подбора параметров :) мингв32, последняя судя по всему, если за вечер новую не выпустили :) gcc ругаться на отсутствие декларации, но саму функцию где то видит, подобрать не сложно.

Comment: Конкретнее можно? Покажите, как вы пытаетесь использовать стандартный вариант: `int vswprintf(wchar_t*, size_t, const wchar_t*, va_list)` и дословно текст ошибки, которую вам выдает mingw.

Comment: Ок, сейчас пойду скриншот организую..

Comment: А кстати, советую поставить MinGW-w64 вместо обычного MinGW. w64 до сих пор обновляется (GCC 8.1), а обычный вроде остановился на GCC 5.x?

Comment: *"Декларацию функции так раскопать и не удалось"* используйте "jump to declaration" или его аналог в вашей IDE

Comment: Или можно просто попробовать скомпилировать `vswprintf()`. В сообщении об ошибке будет указан файл.

Comment: Забавно. Вангую, что MinGW (не w64) официально просто не поддерживает эту функцию, раз ее в хедерах нет. Но непонятно, где ее линковщик находит...

Comment: Ну вроде как все, фото в студию занесено :) но она (функция) там есть, и даже работает.. но по своему.. 8) и собирается в любом варианте.

Comment: Судя по вот [этой](http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Add_func_runtime_C/fn_vsprintf.htm) древней статье, для С++ функция имеет перегруженный вариант (с параметром `count`). А вот для Си, параметра `count` нету. Сама же функция живёт в рантайме msvc (с которым ваша программа линкуется в любом случае), поэтому компиляция и линковка завершается успешно.

Comment: @zed, спасибо, вероятно это так, забавный баг :) или фича.. Оформите ответ, я считаю что он верный, в другом месте ему негде вроде как её раскопать.

Comment: @zed Что-то тут не так. Открыл С11, там count есть, как и в С99.

Comment: Вот ещё в тему: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1728/#4a30/036a Т.е. похоже, что это задеприкейченная реализация в рантайме msvc, которая осталась в хидерах вашего MinGW (вы так и не указали версию). Возможно, в актуальной версии MingGW-w64 такой проблемы нет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Дело в том, что это реализация msvc, а не стандарта Си. В ссылке выше есть объяснение.

Comment: @zed Почитал, теперь все понятно. Надо же.