# mingw 32/64 - как отличить в какой среде оно запущено

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw, кросс-компиляция

mingw32 и mingw64 - как отличить в какой среде оно запущено ?
Вариантов минимум два, или на Linux, или на Windows.

Определять надо в коде, скрипты и прочие внешние средства не подходят.

Пробовал смотреть на `__STDC__`, `__STDC_VERSION__` вроде есть в обеих случаях с -std=gnu99, была надежда что версии разные, но нет, одинаковые.

Всякие системные, типа `__linux` они естественно убраны.

Проверял как кодом, так и:

```
   i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

Задача отличить кросс компиляцию от нативной.
Связано с различной декларацией функций в этих случаях.

Упрощенный пример, есть:

```
#if defined(__MINGW32__)
    int vswprintf(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, va_list);
#endif
```

хочется:

```
#if (defined(__MINGW32__) && !defined(__CROSS_COMPILE_TIME__))
    int vswprintf(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, va_list);
#endif
```

Comment: Как вариант проанализировать sizeof(int). :-)

Comment: что тут подразумевается под "оно"?

Comment: посмотреть в `argv[0]`. С большой вероятностью там будет имя файла приложения. Если в конце exe - значит винда.

Comment: как я правильно понял, есть желание отличать кросс-компиляцию на linux от нативной сборки на win во время компиляции? если так, то странное желание; зачем это может понадобиться? или просто праздный интерес?

Comment: Правильно, отличить кросс компиляцию, а связано с несовпадением нескольких хеадеров и 'ручной' декларацией некоторых функций. При кросс возникает конфликт, надо бы задефайнить эти места.

Comment: @NewView, можно конкретный воспроизводимый пример? ИМХО вместо того чтобы городить лес из `ifdef`'ов стоит попробовать погладить gcc, чтобы он вёл себя корректно и при кросскомпиляции... или правильно настроить среду сборки...

Comment: Пример чего? Объявленных в ручную функций? Если про нее то [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859818/vswprintf-mingw-странная-декларация)

Comment: @NewView, пример демонстрирующий проблему вызванную несовпадением функций и необходимостью ручного объявления... да, если без условной компиляции не обойтись, то будет вполне уместно всё же отличать кросскомпиляцию на уровне системы сборки, а не компилятора...

Comment: То есть в ручную создавать, и тащить от make до кода.. так собственно сейчас и сделано, не очень удобно, прямо скажем. Все же мне кажется должны в чем то отличаться default дефайны отдаваемые компилятором, по которым это дело можно отловить..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате поисков решения перешел от дефайнов компилятора к системе сборки, как и советовал @Fat-Zer.

Но там тоже оказалось не без подводных камней, `mingw64-cmake` полностью симулирует платформу Windows, и про то что оно заводиться из под `Linux` узнать из переменных `Cmake` невозможно.

Нашел вероятно не самый прямой путь, но вроде работает, может пригодиться кому:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
find_program(BUILD_OS_NAME
  uname
  /bin
  /usr/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /sbin
)
mark_as_advanced(
  BUILD_OS_NAME
)

......

if(${BUILD_OS_NAME} STREQUAL "BUILD_OS_NAME-NOTFOUND")
    message("-- No cross-compile mode")
else()
    message("-- Cross-compile UNIX platform to Win")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -D__CROSS_COMPILE_TIME__")
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

Непонятен вопрос, как может быть экзешник запущен в Linux. А Linux-бинарник без `libstdc++.o`. Если не в лом компилируй с `define под что`. Я в винде не компайлил, но вдруг это есть. Попробуй функцию `uname`:

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>
struct utsname buf;
if( ! uname( & buf))  strcmp(buf.sysname,"Linux" )
```

Comment: Нет доступа к этому всему, надо на уровне define в хеадерах.